# ASP .net web method (asmx) image upload through iPhone by passing image as parameters

Tags: asp.net, iphone, webmethod

Let's say I have a webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public void Register(String UserName, String Password)
{

/*
Storing values to database
*/

}
```

I can access this webmethod through iPhone app but I want to pass a user image from iPhone to asp .net so that in my webmethod I can store the image too.

I have seen few tutorial over internet but they all uses aspx pages and posting the form data, I want to use the WebMethod approach and I would like something as follow:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void Register(String UserName, String Password, ImageType image)
    {

    /*
    Storing values to database
    */

    /* 
    copying image to server
    */
    }
```

I hope we can come up with a solution that uses the WebMethod (ASMX) to pass the image as parameter.